# R bootstrap for time series: sieve bootstrap

Tags: r

Is there any R package (or C++) that has sieve bootstrap? (The bootstrap is a method for estimating the distribution of an estimator or test statistic 
by resampling one’s data or a model estimated from the data. This is  more complicated when the data are a time series because bootstrap 
sampling must be carried out in a way that suitably captures the dependence structure of the data
generation process). For time series there is block bootstrap in the package: boot and Maximum Entropy Bootstrap in the package meboot but I would also like to look at sieve bootstrap which I have heard produces better results than the block. I have done ???sos and http://www.rseek.org
but could not find anything. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/016214502760046998) appears to indicate that the `VLMC` package implements the sieve bootstrap with variable length Markov chains.